# Can't install mongodb-enterprise. Error: nothing provides libsasl2.so.2()(64bit)

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install **mongodb-enterprise** on fedora 25, as guided [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-amazon/). I created the repository (as suggested in step 1), but when I run the command `sudo yum install -y mongodb-enterprise`

I get this error:

> Error: nothing provides libsasl2.so.2()(64bit) needed by
>   mongodb-enterprise-tools-3.4.0-1.amzn1.x86_64

and when I try to install **cyrus-sasl-lib** it says *Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.* , I found the command from [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-15.el6_6.2.i686.rpm.html), which provides the library `libsasl2.so.2`. It seems I am stuck.

PS: I've already tried installing from a **Tarball** but that also doesn't seem to be working for me. And I have to use *mongo-shell* version 3.4 only.

Comment: I understand that you're installing Mongo, but it seems like the problems you're running into might be better suited to Superuser. This isn't really about database administration.

Comment: I tried them in `su` also, but nothing helped.

Comment: yeah dude I have no idea why you're trying to install something on a hat.

Comment: I am trying to connect my shell to cluster. I tried with MongoDb Compass too, but It gave me an authentication error, password is correct upto my knowledge.

Comment: @Nikhil Wagh, In place of 'sudo yum install -y mongodb-enterprise' of that run the fedora script like 'dnf install mongodb-org mongodb-org-server' with root user . As already sp_BlitzErik has already told that. And follow my answer step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i saw in your statement , you are going to install `MongoDB Enterprise` in `Fedora 25`. As you said already run

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-enterprise
```

First i would like to say about **Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) & Fedora**.

**Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)** is a product of `Red Hat` and is purchased from `Red Hat` and includes a support contact with `Red Hat` that you renew every year.

**Fedora** was created by Red Hat as a `community-based` open source project that would always have the latest versions as well as trying out new ideas. Items that do well in `Fedora` can make it into `RHEL` at a later time.

I am sure about that you are doing mistake here. Even as per `MongoDB Fedora documentation` in place of

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-enterprise // for Red Hat installation
```

you have to run [Here](https://www.learntutors.com/install-mongodb-fedora-24/)

```
dnf install mongodb-org mongodb-org-server // for Fedora installation
```

**what is dnf?**

> DNF by default uses the global configuration file at /etc/dnf/dnf.conf
>   and all *.repo files found under /etc/yum.repos.d. The latter is
>   typically used for repository configuration and takes precedence over
>   global configuration.

**The steps to install MongoDB on Fedora is pretty simple.**

First, login to the server as `root user`.

Then, we should add the `repository` to download the package. Open a new repo file `mongodb.repo` using below command.

**For 64-bit system**

```
[mongodb]

name=MongoDB Repository

baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/

gpgcheck=0

enabled=1
```

Then exit and save the file with the command `:wq`

Then **installing** `MongoDB` is now one command away

**dnf install mongodb-org mongodb-org-server**

When rompted with `Y / n`, enter `yes` or `y` to download and install the package.

Once installed Start-Up MongoDB

```
[root@fedora]#systemctl start mongod
```

For further your ref [Here](https://www.learntutors.com/install-mongodb-fedora-24/) and [Here](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/database/mongodb/about.html)